# Why doesn't output parameter work?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, output

I am returning an output parameter i.e FormNo from stored procedure in sql. It returns successfully, i checked procedure but in c# code it doesn't return anything.

```
public static Boolean InsertAppliedWorks(int NITNo, int WorkNo, out int FormNo, int ContractorID, decimal FinancialMoney, int OfficeID, int OrgID)
{
    Boolean status = false;

    ClsDatabaseManager dbManager = ClsDatabaseManager.InitializeDbManager(Constants.Databases.TendersConnection);
    try
    {
        FormNo = 0;

        dbManager.Open();
        dbManager.CreateParameters(7);
        dbManager.AddParameters(0, "@NIT_No", NITNo);
        dbManager.AddParameters(1, "@Work_No", WorkNo);
        dbManager.AddParameters(2, "@FormNo", FormNo, ParameterDirection.Output);
        dbManager.AddParameters(3, "@Contractor_ID", ContractorID);
        dbManager.AddParameters(4, "@FinancialMoney", FinancialMoney);
        dbManager.AddParameters(5, "@Organization_ID", OrgID );
        dbManager.AddParameters(6, "@Office_ID", OfficeID);

        status = dbManager.ExecuteNonQuery("InsertAppliedWorks").ToBool();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        dbManager.Close();
        dbManager.Dispose();

    }
    return status;
}
```

Code:

```
protected void btnSavePrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ClsTender.InsertAppliedWorks(NitNo, WorkNo, out formno, ContractorID, Cost.ToDecimal(), bp.LoginMainOfficeID, bp.LoginOrganizationID);

        int TestFormNo = formno;
        Response.Redirect("/forms/general/TenderPrint.aspx?"+"NitNo="+SharedUtility.EncryptURL(NitNo.ToString())+"&WorkNo="+SharedUtility.EncryptURL(WorkNo.ToString()));
    }
}
```

now it returns nothing in FormNo

please help me on this. It has wasted a lot of time and still no signs,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below to retrieve the value:

```
FormNo = Convert.ToInt32(dbManager.Parameters["@FormNo"].Value);
```

Comment: @Cuckoo your output parameter is `FormNo`, you need to get the value of that. Check the edit.